# Cannot see links visible for admins on admin account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4, irb

So I was trying to hide some stuff from normal users:
Helper:

```
def admin
  User.find(:all, :conditions => { :email => ["admin@admin.com"] })
end
```

View:

```
<% if @active_user == admin %>
    <td><%= link_to raw('<i class="icon-pencil icon-white"></i>'), edit_quiz_path(quiz), :class => 'btn btn-info' %></td>
    <td><%= link_to raw('<i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>'), quiz, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Pewien?' }, :class => 'btn btn-danger' %></td>
<% end %>
```

In the end, I logged on my admin account (with email `admin@admin.com`) and nothing showed.

Am I using proper function for finding the user in the db?

Comment: I think `find(:all, ..)` will return an array? just do: `.first` and try?

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work...

Comment: Did you try: `User.find(:all, :conditions => { :email => ["admin@admin.com"] }).first`? What's the value of `@active_user` then?

Comment: yes. Also, I can't find the definition of active user anywhere. I also tried @current_user but doesn't seem to work. I feel it's the query that is wrong, not the view part.

Comment: So the issue is with `@active_user`, you can't see what's the value of `@active_user`? try: `current_user`, if you're using devise or have a helper method defined as `current_user` in your `ApplicationController `

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite the helper method like this, so it would check the user is an admin without doing a query to the DB:

```
def admin?(user)
  user.present? && user.email == 'admin@admin.com'
end
```

Even better, create the method `admin?` in the `User` class.

Comment: Good point, then it doesn't have to send the `user` object at all. it can be: `self.present? && self.email == 'admin@admin.com'`

Comment: But when I try to call for example user.email == "admin@admin" or user.admin == true i get undefined method 'email'

Answer (score 0):

I changed `@current_user == admin` to `current_user.admin?` and suddenly everything is working. So in the end it was the view that was wrong.